# Why do I get console error findIndex() is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a function to replace an element in an array when the quantity of that item is changed. When I have my javascript in a standalone HTML file it runs fine. When it is in a html.twig file I get the error `content.findIndex() is not a function`

Here is my function:

```
function updateCart(item) {
        console.log(item);
        var index = content.findIndex(i => i.id == item.id);
        console.info(index, 'index');
        if (index != -1) {
            content.splice(index, 1);
            content.push(item);
        } else {
            content.push(item);
        }
        console.log(content);
        var printedContent = [];
        content.forEach(function(item) {
            printedContent.push(item.name + " " + item.qty + " Price: " + (item.qty * item.price) + "<br>");
        })

        $("#myCart").html("Your cart contains: <br>" + printedContent);
    }
```

Comment: Version conflict. Multiple instances of jquery maybe?

Comment: @AlexM what does an `Array.prototype` method have to do with jquery?

Comment: In what browser and version? might be one that doesn't support that method and requires a polyfill

Comment: I found that when I had multiple version of javascript scripts included(particulary jquery), it would break odd things at odd times.

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86. Content is an array. I am using jquery and jquery mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an idiot. I still had `content` defined as an empty string, not an empty array.